# Returning functions within Javascript objects

Tags: object-oriented, javascript, node.js

After coming across Douglas Crockford's views on class-free OOP, and doing away with *new* and *this* in Javascript I tried defining an object with its own variable and function, and returning it in a javascript object, as shown below:

```
var newObj = function (name, lang){
    var obj = {
            "name":name,
            "greeter":greeter
    };
    return obj;
};

function greeter (lang){
        switch (lang){
                case "en":return "hi";
                case "es":return "hola";
                default: return "hello";
        }
}


//and finally, use the object    
var name = "john", lang = "es";  
var obj = newObj(name, lang);

console.log(obj.name);
console.log(obj.greeter(lang));
```

I know this code works in NodeJS, but I wonder if it is actually a good idea to do it this way. More specifically, are there any implications/consequences to returning functions within a javascript object that I should be aware of?

Comment: You might have better luck on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't see where you are using JSON in the code you posted, but to answer your question more generally: JSON doesn't support functions. It only supports `true`, `false`, `null`, numbers, strings, arrays, and maps.

Comment: My bad, I meant javascript object, as in `var obj = {
            "name":name,
            "greeter":greeter
    };`

Comment: @RobertHarvey when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Since I am the OP, should I delete this question here? Indeed, it has gotten more responses on the code review SE site.

Comment: This is really a better fit here, as it's about a general software design, but just uses some example code to illustrate the general question.   Code review is about making specific production code better, not about solving general design questions, and the question over there is getting comments to that effect.

Comment: thank you, kind sir. my question was indeed about this overall approach..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are just objects.  As such, there is no particular reason not to pass them around as parts of other objects.  In fact, may JavaScript libraries do this, for instance, letting you pass in an object containing a `success` and an `error` callback.

As a way of doing OOP in JavaScript, that's a perfectly reasonable way of doing things, and I've worked on real production code did that.  Whether it's the best way to do it is a matter of opinion.